# Proving the re-weighted graph have the same shortest path as before

Tags: math, graph-theory

Say that G′ is a graph re-weighted from G using the rule: w′(u,v)=w(u,v)−f(u)+f(v), where f always produce the positive results for any nodes. Can we prove that the shortest path PG from s to t remains the shortest path from s to t in G′?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a path:

```
P = <v1,v2,v3, ..., v(n-2), v(n-1), vn>
```

then the weight of the path is given by:

```
w(P) = w(v1,v2) + w(v2,v3) + ... w(v(n-2), v(n-1)) + w(v(n-1), vn)
```

If you re-weight the graph then the re-weighted value of the path is:

```
w'(P) = w'(v1,v2) + w'(v2,v3) + ... + w'(v(n-2), v(n-1)) + w'(v(n-1), vn)
      =   w(v1,v2) - f(v1) + f(v2)
        + w(v2,v3) - f(v2) + f(v3)
        + w(v3,v4) - f(v3) + f(v4)
          ...
        + w(v(n-3),v(n-2)) - f(v(n-3)) + f(v(n-2))
        + w(v(n-2),v(n-1)) - f(v(n-2)) + f(v(n-1))
        + w(v(n-1),vn)     - f(v(n-1)) + f(vn)
      = w(P) - f(v1) + f(vn)
```

Notice how the re-weighting factors cancel out in the middle of the path and are only applied to the end points.

Now given the set of all paths from `v1` to `vn` then re-weighting the paths according to the re-weighting formula you've give would change the cost of all paths by the same amount (since the end-points are identical and the re-weighting only changes the cost of the path depending on the end-points). So if one of those paths is the minimum cost path then it will still be the minimum cost path after re-weighting.

Comment: Thank you : ) But couldn't it form a negative loop?

Comment: No - because for any given vertex in the middle of the path then the negative re-weighting factor applied to outbound edge will be cancelled by the equal positive re-weighting factor applied to the inbound edge. So, if there is not a negative-cost loop in the original minimal-cost path then there can't be one in the re-weighted path.